# change sender email address in php form to recipient

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to create a simple php email form that sends the submitted contents to a specified address, but the problem I'm trying to fix is the address the email is being sent from — currently, it sends from myusername@myhostingservice.com, but I want to be able to change that to a simple no-reply@mydomain.com or something else.

```
<?php 

$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="$message";

$recipient = "reciever@example.com";

$subject = "question";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $header, '-fno-reply@mydomain.com') or die("Error!");

header("Location: webpage_user_is_redirected_to.html");

?>
```

Comment: don't use mail() use a third party library like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 5th parameter of the mail function:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $header, '-fno-replay@mydomain.com');
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass additional
>   flags as command line options to the program configured to be used
>   when sending mail, as defined by the sendmail_path configuration
>   setting. For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender
>   address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.

Comment: I do not see your `$header`? If you have not any other header info use null `mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, null, '-fno-replay@mydomain.com');`

Comment: And there is no need to pass `$_POST['message'];` over 3 layers of variables: `mail($recipient, $subject, $_POST['message'], null, '-fno-replay@mydomain.com');`

Comment: Thanks it's working great now! So it will start with $formcontent now?

Comment: `$formcontent` is the posted message from the form. You need to wrap it into a nice message: `"Dear Luke, the message from the form is " . $_POST['message'];` :)